# Using each in jquery with a click event for a button that corresponds to a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have three buttons, each with an ID that corresponds to their order. When a button is clicked a paragraph that corresponds to that order should hide itself with `.hide()`.

My problem is how do you use `.each()` to loop though the buttons by finding which has been clicked using a `click()` event to hide the corresponding paragraphs?

Comment: We really need to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event to all of your id's that start with something, let's assume "order-#", then traverse to the closest `<p>` element and hide it.

```
$('[id^=order-]').click(function(){ $(this).closest('p').hide() });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` to traverse all the buttons (identified by a common class) adding a click-handler which will make use of the button's id to select and hide the appropriate paragraph. Something like

```
$('.button').each(function (buttonIndex, buttonEl) {
    $(buttonEl).click(function () {
        $('.par' + $(this).attr('id')).hide();
    });
});
```

Here's the [relevant fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zv95xtc/1/).

Note that there's many ways to avoid using the button's id to target the appropriate paragraph, for example by using the `buttonIndex` param above.

And generally speaking - as [ohgodwhy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28397197/612262) indicates - there's ways of doing this in an altogether more concise manner.